# Trying to pull a value out of a kendo popup window using Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, kendo-ui

I'm trying to pull a value out of a kendo popup window but can't seem to get the right combo/syntax.
Im looking for **9070009** in the "dipatchIdentLablel"

I have tried:

```
.Document.getElementById("AddSucessWindow").Value  'I know, too broad, too many possibilities
.Document.getElementById("AddSucessWindow").Text
.Document.getElementById("AddSucessWindow").getElementById("dispatchIdentLablel").Value
.Document.getElementById("AddSucessWindow").getElementById("dispatchIdentLablel").Text
.Document.getElementById("dispachIdentLablel").Value
.Document.getElementById("dispachIdentLablel").Text
.Document.getElementById("dispachIdentLablel").getElementsByName("dispatchIdentLablel").Value
.Document.getElementById("dispachIdentLablel").getElementsByName("dispatchIdentLablel").Text
.Document.getElementById("dispachIdentLablel").getElementsByName("dispatchIdentLablel").innerText
.Document.getElementById("dispachIdentLablel").getElementsByName("dispatchIdentLablel").HTML
.Document.getElementById("AddSucessWindow").getElementsByTagName("span").Value
.Document.getElementById("AddSucessWindow").getElementsByTagName("span").Text
```

No errors on any, but the result is"empty" on all

Here is a portion of the web page code. I've removed a bunch of unneccessary stuff for ease of reading.

```
<div tabindex="0" class="k-window-content k-content" id="AddSucessWindow" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="AddSucessWindow_wnd_title" data-role="window">
  <div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="columnLabel">
                    <label for="Dispatch_Load_Id:">Dispatch Load Id:</label>
                </td>
                <td class="columnData">
                <span id="dispatchIdentLablel" name="dispatchIdentLablel"></span>
                 9070009        '<<--Shows as element  (text)
                </td>
           </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="divCenter">
    <button Type="Button" id="AddSucessWindowClose">Close</button><script>
jQuery(function(){jQuery("#AddSucessWindowClose").kendoButton({});});
</script>
</div>
```

I can get the button to close the window using this

```
.Document.getElementById("AddSucessWindowClose").Click
```

I know I'm overlooking something or have the syntax wrong. Any insight appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `querySelector()` looking for the `columnData` class:

```
.Document.querySelector(".columnData").innerText
```

Note that this worked for me when testing with just the HTML in the OP. If there are other elements with the same class on the page, may have to tweak it.

Comment: Yes there are several elements in the window, I only showed the one I was interested in. I may be able to use an index number, since it's in the same location/order every time (actually the last index before the close button), or rule out the other items because they are all variables except for this one. Thanks Bruce. I'll work on it.

Comment: I used this line `myId2 = .Document.querySelector(".columnData").innerText` but results were `"""`. I'll try some other things.

Comment: @Mitch - Yeah, IIRC `querySelectorAll` returns a list, so if it's always the same one, you should be able to do say `.Document.querySelectorAll(".columnData")[2].innerText`.